# Not receiving mail from domain mail-accounts

Tags: email

I am having a problem where i get a bounce whenever i send a mail to my email address xxx@mydomain.com, from xxx@anyotherdomain.com. I tested this with about 10 of my email accounts and none of them work.

However I am able to receive mails from accounts like xxx@hotmail.com or xxx@gmail.com.

I get this bounce :

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:

However no error codes. If anyone can help me or point me at the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sending any sort of attachments?  are you certain that the account was created successfully on your hosting?  Also if there was a way for you to provide us with the full message header (omitting addresses) that would be ideal to see if there is anything else we can acertain

Answer (score 0):

You should see a more detailed error message below what you quoted. But I would check to see if you have an SPF record for either of the two domains and make sure it is set correctly.